# Multi typed calculator using bison/flex

Tags: bison, flex-lexer

I'm trying to implement a multi typed calculator using both flex and bison.
My problem is how to write a grammar that respect my goal.

fox example : 5 + 3.4, the result should be a float number.
              5 + 5, an integer result.
              ...
              etc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [semantic type checking analysis in bison](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11199778/semantic-type-checking-analysis-in-bison)

Comment: Here's another possibly relevant previous answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25818877/bison-flex-reduce-reduce-identifier-in-different-production/25819255#25819255